# Ember.js: livereload server not working

Tags: javascript, ember.js, livereload

Some days ago everything was good. But now, when I run Ember on my mac os:

```
ember s
```

I've got:

```
version: 2.4.1
Livereload server on http://localhost:49152
Serving on http://localhost:4200/

Build successful - 849ms.

Slowest Trees                                 | Total               
----------------------------------------------+---------------------
SourceMapConcat: Concat: Vendor /assets/ve... | 100ms               
Babel                                         | 75ms                
Babel                                         | 59ms                

Slowest Trees (cumulative)                    | Total (avg)         
----------------------------------------------+---------------------
Babel (13)                                    | 305ms (23 ms)       
SourceMapConcat: Concat: Vendor /asset... (1) | 100ms
```

When I change file I've got in console:

```
file changed templates/components/prospect-panel.hbs

Build successful - 200ms.

Slowest Trees (cumulative)                    | Total (avg)         
----------------------------------------------+---------------------
Babel (13)                                    | 23ms (1 ms)
```

But in browser I see:

```
ember-cli-live-reload.js:6 

GET http://localhost:49152/livereload.js?snipver=1 net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE
```

Why http://localhost:49152/livereload.js?snipver=1 is not accessible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Possibily any other application is using this port. You can change the port by adding the following line to the `.ember-cli` file.

```
"live-reload-port":49155
```